# Manipulate a single element of vector

Tags: java, vector

I'm currently trying to manipulate a single element of a vector in Java. If I try to do this with elementAt(i) or get(i) in a loop, the whole vector is still changed. I'm looking for a way to try and do this while still using vectors (as I use them throughout the rest of my program).

I have tried to clone my vector into a temporary one, then remove all elements of the vector except the one to be manipulated, but to no avail.

Here is my code segment:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
        if (shapes.get(i) != null){
            g2.setColor(colorSelected());
            if(fill.isSelected() && !((String)shapesList.getSelectedItem() == "Line")){
                g2.fill(shapes.elementAt(i));
            } else {
                g2.draw(shapes.elementAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that's happening is I'm trying to either fill/draw/change the color of the single next element drawn in my makeshift paint program, but it changes every shape.

Any tips (or an explanation as to why this is happening) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(String)shapesList.getSelectedItem() == "Line"` You should use `equals` to compare String instances

Comment: You should probably change the shape of the selected item.

Comment: Appreciate it @Robin. I did that late at night and never noticed my mistake there.

Comment: My guess is that @Robin has nailed the problem, but since your descriptions, "it changes every shape" and "the whole vector is changed" are quite vague, I can't tell just what the problem is.

Comment: Hey @ajb, what Robin told me to fix had nothing to do with actually changing every shape on the screen, just a fix to my if-statement. So what's happening is when I check fill on my user interface, or uncheck it, the next time I draw a shape on the screen every shape (rather than just the one I draw) will be manipulated to be filled or outlined, instead of the single shape I drew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for this problem is that `shapes` does not in fact contain multiple shapes, but only multiple references to the same Shape object. The bug would then be in the part of the code that fills the Vector.

Sidenote: the `Vector` class is old and obsolescent. It should be avoided in favor of `ArrayList` unless you're using an API that really demands a `Vector` (which does happen in Swing). If you're using tutorials or books that teach you to use `Vector`, then they are probably more than 10 years old and should be avoided.

Comment: I see. I did not know that. Thank you for the information. I'll begin to change my program to work with ArrayList if I can.